# R_splitting a data frame based on column-wise NA value occurance

Tags: r, dataframe, split, grouping

Sample data

```
set.seed(16)
aaa <- 1:1000
aaa[round(runif(100,1,1000))] <- NA
aaa.df <- as.data.frame(matrix(aaa, ncol=5))
```

I want the `aaa.df` to be split into multiple groups based on which column(s) contains NA value(s), so for example, if 10th, 16th, 200th rows has NA value in the same column, I want these rows to be in one group and so on. It should also work when a. there is no NA values in a row and b. there is multiple NA values in a row.

I also want to keep the original row number when grouping.

**Edit:** To make it clearer this is the expected output (Obtained using Taufi's answer, but I am still looking for a more elegant way)

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 119 x 6
    V1.y  V2.y  V3.y  V4.y  V5.y    V6
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1   201   401   601   801     1
 2     2   202   402   602   802     2
 3     3   203   403   603   803     3
 4     4   204   404   604   804     4
 5     5   205   405   605   805     5
 6     6   206   406   606   806     6
 7     7   207   407   607   807     7
 8     8   208   408   608   808     8
 9     9   209   409   609   809     9
10    10   210   410   610   810    10
# ... with 109 more rows

[[2]]
# A tibble: 14 x 6
    V1.y  V2.y  V3.y  V4.y  V5.y    V6
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1    20   220   420   620    NA    20
 2    32   232   432   632    NA    32
 3    47   247   447   647    NA    47
 4    70   270   470   670    NA    70
 5    85   285   485   685    NA    85
 6    92   292   492   692    NA    92
 7   129   329   529   729    NA   129
 8   132   332   532   732    NA   132
 9   137   337   537   737    NA   137
10   151   351   551   751    NA   151
11   152   352   552   752    NA   152
12   168   368   568   768    NA   168
13   178   378   578   778    NA   178
14   181   381   581   781    NA   181

[[3]]
# A tibble: 15 x 6
    V1.y  V2.y  V3.y  V4.y  V5.y    V6
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1    11   211   411    NA   811    11
 2    37   237   437    NA   837    37
 3    62   262   462    NA   862    62
 4    82   282   482    NA   882    82
 5    83   283   483    NA   883    83
 6    89   289   489    NA   889    89
 7   107   307   507    NA   907   107
 8   115   315   515    NA   915   115
 9   116   316   516    NA   916   116
10   117   317   517    NA   917   117
11   118   318   518    NA   918   118
12   165   365   565    NA   965   165
13   176   376   576    NA   976   176
14   189   389   589    NA   989   189
15   200   400   600    NA  1000   200

[[4]]
# A tibble: 1 x 6
   V1.y  V2.y  V3.y  V4.y  V5.y    V6
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    12   212   412    NA    NA    12

[[5]]
# A tibble: 16 x 6
    V1.y  V2.y  V3.y  V4.y  V5.y    V6
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1    17   217    NA   617   817    17
 2    28   228    NA   628   828    28
 3    31   231    NA   631   831    31
 4    48   248    NA   648   848    48
 5    58   258    NA   658   858    58
 6    72   272    NA   672   872    72
 7    80   280    NA   680   880    80
 8   126   326    NA   726   926   126
 9   144   344    NA   744   944   144
10   145   345    NA   745   945   145
11   149   349    NA   749   949   149
12   153   353    NA   753   953   153
13   186   386    NA   786   986   186
14   190   390    NA   790   990   190
15   192   392    NA   792   992   192
16   196   396    NA   796   996   196
and so on..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my previous more brute-force kind of answer, I came up with the following way more elegant one-liner that avoids any unnecessary joins or intermediate assignment steps. Since you already accepted my previous answer, I let that be as it stands and add the conceptually different one-liner below. The idea is to `split()` the data.frame based on `paste`d column numbers from `which()` that indicate the presence of `NA`.

```
split(aaa.df, 
           apply(aaa.df, 1, 
                            function(x) paste(which(is.na(x)), collapse = ",")))
```

**Output**

```
$`1`
    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
77  NA 277 477 677 877
93  NA 293 493 693 893
97  NA 297 497 697 897
109 NA 309 509 709 909
119 NA 319 519 719 919
140 NA 340 540 740 940
154 NA 354 554 754 954
158 NA 358 558 758 958
171 NA 371 571 771 971
172 NA 372 572 772 972

$`1,2,3`
   V1 V2 V3  V4  V5
51 NA NA NA 651 851

$`1,3,5`
   V1  V2 V3  V4 V5
75 NA 275 NA 675 NA

$`1,4`
    V1  V2  V3 V4  V5
194 NA 394 594 NA 994

$`1,4,5`
   V1  V2  V3 V4 V5
49 NA 249 449 NA NA
 ...
```

and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

A quick, but not very elegant solution would be as follows. Note that the original row number later is in `V6`.

```
aaa.df %<>% mutate(Rownum = 1:nrow(aaa.df))
Aux.df <- cbind(is.na(aaa.df[, 1:(ncol(aaa.df) - 1)]), 1:nrow(aaa.df)) %>% 
                    as.data.frame %>% 
                            group_by(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5) %>%  
                                          group_split
Sol <- lapply(Aux.df, function(x) inner_join(x, aaa.df, by = c("V6"="Rownum")) %>%
                                 select(V1.y, V2.y, V3.y, V4.y, V5.y, V6))
```

**Output**

```
    > Sol
[[1]]
# A tibble: 119 x 6
    V1.y  V2.y  V3.y  V4.y  V5.y    V6
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1   201   401   601   801     1
 2     2   202   402   602   802     2
 3     3   203   403   603   803     3
 4     4   204   404   604   804     4
 5     5   205   405   605   805     5
 6     6   206   406   606   806     6
 7     7   207   407   607   807     7
 8     8   208   408   608   808     8
 9     9   209   409   609   809     9
10    10   210   410   610   810    10
# ... with 109 more rows

[[2]]
# A tibble: 14 x 6
    V1.y  V2.y  V3.y  V4.y  V5.y    V6
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1    20   220   420   620    NA    20
 2    32   232   432   632    NA    32
 3    47   247   447   647    NA    47
 4    70   270   470   670    NA    70
 5    85   285   485   685    NA    85
 6    92   292   492   692    NA    92
 7   129   329   529   729    NA   129
 8   132   332   532   732    NA   132
 9   137   337   537   737    NA   137
10   151   351   551   751    NA   151
11   152   352   552   752    NA   152
12   168   368   568   768    NA   168
13   178   378   578   778    NA   178
14   181   381   581   781    NA   181
....
```

and so on ...

Comment: Thanks @Taufi. It works. I will just wait for more answers before accepting the most elegant solution.